# Exporting API result into CSV file (delimiting the right way?)

Tags: python, api, csv

I am having trouble with exporting the API result below into a csv file. It seems to me that the delimiter is "," (3-character). What is the best way to delimit the result and create a clean CSV file?

Note: This API can help determine whether an individual address is up to date by inputting individual address, first name, last name, etc.

### CSV file:

For example, as you can see in the picture below, the exported csv file has 4 values of address that are separated in 4 different cells (also containing a column name - AddressLine2)

(I initially input 4 rows.)

[image]

### API result (from request.get):

> {"CASSReportLink":"https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/CASSReport.aspx?tkenrpt=YvBDs39g52jKhLJyl5RgHKpuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RHVDSbt7tI8uGzEWwEIEwt6acz9MoXfDckO7OTUvVcuA=","NCOAReportLink":"https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/Reports/NCOAReport.aspx?tkenrpt=8anQa424W7NYg8ueROFirapuj5HwDMe1pE2lcQrczqRiG3/3y5yMlixj5S7lIvLJpDyAOkD8fE8vDCg56s3UogNuAkdTbS2aqoYF5FvyovUjnXzoQaHaL8TaQbwyCQ2RHVDSbt7tI8uGzEWwEIEwt6acz9MoXfDckO7OTUvVcuA=","Records":[{"AddressExtras":"","AddressKey":"78704,78704","AddressLine1":"                                                            ,                                                            ,                                                            ,STE C-100                                                   ","AddressLine2":"1009 W MONROE ST                                            ,1600 S 5TH ST                                               ,1008 W MILTON ST                                            ,3939 BEE CAVES RD                                           ","AddressTypeCode":"","BaseMelissaAddressKey":"","CarrierRoute":"","City":"Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ","CityAbbreviation":"Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ,Austin                                            ","CompanyName":"","CountryCode":"US","CountryName":"United States","DeliveryIndicator":"","DeliveryPointCheckDigit":"","DeliveryPointCode":"","MelissaAddressKey":"","MoveEffectiveDate":"","MoveTypeCode":"","PostalCode":"78704,78704,78704,78746","RecordID":"1","Results":"AE07","State":"","StateName":"TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ,TX                                                ","Urbanization":""}],"TotalRecords":"1","TransmissionReference":"1353","TransmissionResults":"","Version":"4.0.4.48"}
>   [Finished in 1.1s]

### My code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\users\testu\documents\travis_test.csv",delimiter = ',',na_values="nan")

url = 'https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover' 
payload = {'t': '1353', 'id': '138fg88jr3r', 'jobid': '1', 'act': 'NCOA, CCOA', 'cols': 'AddressLine1,AddressLine2,City,PostalCode,Results,State', 'opt': 'ProcessingType: Standard', 'List': 'test', 'full': df["appr_owner_name"], 'a1': df["prop_year_addr_line1"], 'a2': df["prop_year_addr_line2"], 'city': df["prop_addr_city"], 'state': df["prop_addr_state"], 'postal': df["prop_addr_zip"], 'ctry': 'USA'}

response = requests.get(
    url, params=payload,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'} # Using JSON here for readability in the response
)


r = response.text
print(r)

with open(r'C:\users\testu\documents\travis3.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(r)
```

Comment: But you're not using the `csv` module that you imported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API return value is not in csv format, it is in json format. Tou can't just write it in the file.

You have to actually read it as json, extract the data and format it in the way you want in your csv file. Example:

```
r = response.json
with open(r'C:\users\testu\documents\travis3.csv', 'w+') as f:
    cf = csv.writer(f)
    cf.writerow(r['Records'][0]['AddressLine2'].split(','))
```